# Jenkins Ivy plug-in: looking for wrong ivy.xml file

Tags: jenkins, ivy

I have an Ivy job in Jenkins that is supposed to go into component folders and build the components based on their ivy.xml files. For example, I have a `bundle` project and it contains folders with the various components and `ivy.xml` files in them. For example:

```
bundle/componentA/ivy.xml
bundle/componentB/ivy.xml
bundle/componentC/ivy.xml
```

I expect the job to go into the component folders and build the components (the `Build modules as separate jobs` option is checked). However, the console output shows this:

`Error while reading the default Ivy 2.1 settings: failed to load settings from file:/var/lib/jenkins/slave/workspace/Build/MyProj/Build-bundle/ivy3112090154706031317xml`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded Jenkins to v2 (it was 1.x before) and the problem was solved.